# Alternative to IEEEeqnarray

Tags: align

By recommendation from *The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX*, I have been using the `IEEEeqnarray` environment a lot, since it solved many of the rather annoying problems related to the `align`environment. But because of its limited documentation and the changes it causes to other environments like `enumerate`, I have started to look for alternatives.

The advantages for the `IEEEeqnarray` are:

- The command `\IEEEyesnumber`, which allows you to insert equation numbers in an `IEEEeqnarray*` environment. That made it a lot easier to just insert equation numbers in one row without having to write `\nonumber` at the end of every single line like in the `align` environment.
- It included the option to edit the width of the columns, like in the `array` environment. The syntax was: `\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}`, and it was a really nice option.

Does anybody know a way to achieve the same advantages with other environments?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  I'd use `align`, or `alignedat` (and the starred variants), or `array`.  Those can do everything mentioned above.   An excellent reference for math mode is Herbert Voss'  [comprehensive review of mathematics in (La)TeX](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/math/voss/mathmode/).

Comment: I know that the `align` environment can do this, but not as easily as what I mention above. For instance, if I have four rows, but only want an equation number on the last one, I have to write `\nonumber` after each of the other four lines. But in the `IEEEeqnarray*`, I could just write `IEEEyesnumber` after the fourth line, which was a lot easier.

Comment: With the `align*` numbers are not added, but if include a `\tag` to the end of the equation you can number them.  So this would be used instead of `IEEEyesnumber`.

Comment: Yes, but that would not support dynamical numbering and referencing. `\IEEEyesnumber` does exactly that. With this, you can write a `\label` and then reference it just like in the `align` environment.

Comment: an alternative that adds just a single number to a multi-line display is to nest the `aligned` environment inside `equation`.  see the `amsmath` documentation for other possibilities (`texdoc amsmath`).  this does support automatic numbering and cross-referencing, using the number assigned for `equation`.

Comment: If the `IEEEtrantools` package is loaded with the `retainorgcmds` option standard LaTeX environments like `enumerate` are not changed. The `IEEEeqnarray` environment is documented in Appendix F of the [`IEEEtrantools` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you main reason for using `IEEEeqnarray*` is the fact that you can select to number only a certain equation.  You can achieve this with using `align*` and then `tag`/`\label` the equations you want numbered.

Below I have defined a `\IEEEyesnumber` which provides the required functionality, and you can `\label` and `\ref` them as desired:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\IEEEyesnumber}{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a &= b \\
    c &= d \label{eqn:Align} \\
    f & = g
\end{align}


\begin{align*}
    a &= b \\
    c &= d \IEEEyesnumber\label{eqn:AlignStar} \\
    f & = g
\end{align*}

In \verb|align| the equation was \ref{eqn:Align}, and in \verb|align*| it was \ref{eqn:AlignStar}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

i've stolen this example from peter grill and made a slight change -- using `aligned` within `equation` to get just one number for the second display.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    a &= b \\
    c &= d \label{eqn:Align} \\
    f & = g
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    a &= b \\
    c &= d \\
    f & = g
\end{aligned}
\label{eqn:Aligned}
\end{equation}

In \verb|align| the equation was \ref{eqn:Align}, and in the structure
using \verb|aligned| it was \ref{eqn:Aligned}.
\end{document}
```

for more possibilities, see the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath` from a
tex live installation).

Comment: `texdoc amsmath` also works in MikTeX.

Answer (score 6):

To prevent IEEEtrantools from altering the list environments, just load it
with its `retainorgcmds` option:

```
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
```

This is now the default operation for version 1.3 and later of [IEEEtrantools](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetrantools).

Version 1.3 also now works properly with `hyperref` links.

The documentation of IEEEeqnarray is extensive. See Appendix F of the IEEEtran HOWTO: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/
as well as Section XI for the IEEEitemize, IEEEenumerate, etc. lists.
Lastly, additional IEEEtrantools.sty specific documentation can be found in the IEEEtrantools_doc.txt file.